# Replace linendings in csv before open it

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I have a csv which i read by fopen and then fgetcsv:

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
$handle = fopen($uploadDir.$fileName,"r");
while (($aCell = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    //GO THROUGH ROWS
}
```

my problem is that the csv from windows have CRLF (\r\n) or LF (\n) as linefeed characters. Sometimes i have a csv from mac which uses CRLF and sometimes CR (mostly in text columns with st. html text)

The CR breaks the fgetcsv so that i do not get the correct structure of columns and rows as in the header columns "defined", i have with the windoof ones.

How can i replace CRs (\r) with LF (\n) in that csv before going through the lines?

**EDIT**
I tried Passerbys Idea it works. Thx for your Tips

```
            $file_contents = file_get_contents($uploadDir.$fileName);
            $file_cont_tmp = str_replace("\r","\r\n",$file_contents);
            $file_cont_new = str_replace("\r\n\n","\r\n",$file_cont_tmp);
            file_put_contents($uploadDir.$fileName,$file_cont_new);
```

Comment: Have you looked at `PHP_EOL`? It is an intelligent line separator constant, if you explode on it, perhaps you can repair the file before processing it.

Comment: @Flosculus hm i hear that first time. But what i read so far maybe it can help with my problem. But how to implement it?

Comment: Well first you need to clarify how you can split the lines.  Explode the content of the file by various separators, including that constant.  Also look into `str_getcsv()`, using that will save you needing to re-save the file.

Comment: @Flosculus Im not that php crack so maybe you are kind to give a little example? In the moment i cannot follow you what to do with PHP_EOL or str_getcsv()

Comment: If your data do not contain line breaks in "cell"s you can simply `file_put_contents(str_replace(...,file_get_contents(file)));`.